# physics.OverlapBox bigger than Gizmo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to use `physics.OverlapBox` as a Check Area, And wanted to use `Gizmos` to visualize it.

They're both the same size.. or at least should be, But it seems the Check Area is bigger than the Gizmo.

Both `physics.OverlapBox` and `Gizmos` are at a point in front of the player.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUOjXDGZCrg)

I know the code is not great but this is just to test it out:

```
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = new Color(0.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        Gizmos.DrawCube(_shootArea.position, new Vector3(2,2,2));
    }

void Update()
    {

        Collider[] footballInRange = Physics.OverlapBox(_shootArea.position, new Vector3(2,2,2), Quaternion.identity, _layerFootball);
        foreach (var footBall in footballInRange)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ball In Collider At " + Time.frameCount);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) and [Gizmos.DrawCube](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawCube.html) declarations.

> public static Collider[] OverlapBox(Vector3 center, Vector3 **halfExtents**, [...]);

> public static void DrawCube(Vector3 center, Vector3 **size**);

If you use the same dimensions for both the overlapbox will be twice as big as the displayed gizmo.

Either make the gizmo twice as large or the box half as small.